# bounded analytic function as a power series

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables

Suppose $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\frac{(i x)^k}{k!}$$ where $$a_k=k!\int_0^1 p_k(y_{k-1})\int_0^{y_{k-1}}p_{k-1}(y_{k-2})\cdots \int_0^{y_1}p_1(y_0) dy_0\cdots dy_{k-2}\;dy_{k-1}$$ for functions $p_i>0$ and $p_i=p_j$ if $i=j \mod 2$. Is $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$?

This is a generalization of situation when $p_1=p_2=p$. In this case, $$f(x)=\exp\left(ix \int_0^1 p(y)dy\right),$$
and we know that $f(x)$ is bounded.

More generally, is there any assumptions that we can put on $a_k$ to make sure $f(x)$ is bounded?

Any reference is appreciated.

Comment: If you also require that the sum defining $f(x)$ converges *absolutely* for all $x$, then the necessary and sufficient condition is that $\forall k>0: a_k = 0$.

Comment: @MarkFischler Sorry? I thought the power series always converges absolutely...

Comment: @MarkFischler: $f(x)=\sin x$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ and the Taylor series converges absolutely.

Comment: Are all $a_k$ real? This is important, as for instance if  $a_k\geq 0$ for all $k$ then surely $f$ is bounded if and only if all $a_k$ vanish except $a_0$. Also, what kind of condition do you expect (*i.e.* algebraic, analytic, or... in terms of $a_k$)?

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier Not necessarily. Let $E$ be a matrix-valued function on $\mathbb{R}$. Consider repeated integral of $E$. $A_k=\int_0^{1}E(x_{k-1})\int_0^{x_{k-1}}E(x_{k-2})\cdots\int_0^{x_1}E(x_0) d x_0 \cdots d x_{k-2} d x_{k-1}$. And $a_k$ is one of the entries in $A_k$.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier Let us say $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\frac{(i x)^k}{k!},$$ and $a_k$ are assumed to be real.

Comment: Okay, so could you please edit your answer *once* to make this clear to all (and then please stop editing your question for a while...).

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier Sorry about the editing. I will stick to the current question.

Comment: Anyway, you realize that the newer version is essentially equivalent to the original formulation (by taking real and imaginary parts), don't you? Since you haven't explained in which terms (algebraic, analytic,...) you want a necessary and sufficient condition, it seems difficult to answer the question as it stands.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier Ah! You are right... However, I do not think I can say any more about $a_k$... However, I am interested in any results that are related this problem.

Comment: I think that if you were more specific this would be an interesting question. Bounded coefficients are sufficient, but it's not obvious that's best possible. Changing variables to $x=re^{i\theta}$ and considering Hilbert transformation might be worth considering.

Comment: @KevinSmith: are your sure boundedness of  $(a_k)_k$ is sufficient ?

Comment: @QijunTan         May be this link would be some how related to the question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle

Comment: @Loic Teyssier. Certainly not now - the question has been changed.

Comment: @KevinSmith: Yes indeed...

Comment: @QijunTan: it is really bad form to change a question so drastically as you did, especially after so many comments and an *accepted* answer have been committed. You should/could have asked a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is bounded, the Laplace transform

$${\mathscr L}f(s) = \int_0^\infty f(x) e^{-sx}\; dx$$ 
is analytic in the open right half plane, and the same goes for the Laplace transform of $\widetilde{f}(x) = f(-x)$.
On the other hand, $|a_k| \le C^k$ implies that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k i^k s^{-k-1}$ converges absolutely to an analytic function $g(s)$ for $|s|> C$, with
$|g(s)| \le 1/(|s|-|C|)$ and
this agrees with $\mathscr L f(s)$ and $- \mathscr L \widetilde{f}(-s)$ in the intersections of this region with the open right and left half planes.
Thus $\mathscr L f(s)$ can be analytically continued to a function analytic in
$\mathbb C \backslash I$ where $I$ is the closed line segment from $-Ci$ to $Ci$.

Conversely, if $g(s)$ is an analytic function in $\mathbb C \backslash I$ with $\lim_{|s| \to \infty} g(s) = 0$, the Bromwich integral defines  $f(x)$ on $\mathbb R$ that has this Laplace transform.  However, this is not necessarily bounded.  A sufficient condition is that
$g(s) = \int_{-C}^C  (s-it)^{-1} d\mu(t)$ where $\mu$ is a signed measure on $[-C,C]$, which translates to $f(x) = \int_{-C}^C \exp(itx)\; d\mu(t)$.
This is also necessary in the case that $g(s)$ is a rational function: in that case it means that the only singularities of $g$ are simple poles.